# How to delete (and prevent) extra headers from appearing in Word while modifying a template

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2016

I downloaded a resume template for word and started modifying it to suit my preferences. But for some reason, whenever i try to modify the contents of the first-page header, a new header pops up in the second page. I couldn't delete it even after trying 20 different ways I found on google.

This wouldn't really make much sense in words so i've linked the template so anyone can download it and see clearly what's wrong.

The new header pops up when you try to access the field in the old header. It won't place the new header permanently until content control is removed and the spacing is modified.

If this isn't possible, can i remove the whole header section so i can just make do with text boxes and raw shapes

I intend to clean up the resume to 1 page in the end but the second page will stay there because of the extra header even if i try to delete it

[Template download link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1W-p8HZM_TAYWePxCUNXJFtnLyXRmFyCg)

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to do this as a comment because I'm not sure it's what you're seeing. But it's too long for a comment.

The main problem seems actually to be that the table containing the body text flows over into the second page. That's not how it looks when I open it in Google Docs. If you reduce the font size of the text in the table (say, to 10 points) then the second page disappears. When I do that here, no second header appears when you modify the name in the Content Control in the title.

If that does not work, the following may help you understand what you need to change.

When I download the document and look at the XML (inside the .docx). the document has a header1.xml and a footer1.xml. It probably wasn't created in Word. If you create a new one-page document using Word and look inside the .docx, I think you will see *three header* files header1.xml, header2.xml and header3.xml (for the "primary header", the "firstpage header" and the one of the odd/even page headers).

So I thnk what is happening is that as soon as you try to modify the header on page one, Word creates those other two headers and displays their content. In fact, there is no content except for a Paragraph Mark. The Paragraph mark is for a paragraph with style Header, and that style has been set up to have a yellow border and quite a lot of vertical space.

So that's why a big yellow rectangle suddenly pops up on page two when you modify the name.

If you reduce the font size of the table text as I mentioned before, the document should go back to being a one-page document and the page 2 header should disappear. If that isn't happening, I can only guess that you have a page break or section break, or have formatted one of the paragraphs so that it starts on a new page.

If you end up needing a two-page document and want to get rid of the yellow box, it would probably be enough to select the page 2 header and change its paragraph style, e.g. to Normal.